# Localization for Kik applications

Tags: kik

Kik has mentioned that it has 120M users from 225 countries.
That way Kik should support localization for its UI and Kik apps also.

So, the question is how HTML5/JS application can get current user locale to show UI using user locale?

Thanks,
Serg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kik is a mobile web browser. That means it follows the regular standards set out for browsers in terms of localization.

You have two basic options:

- browser-side: JavaScript has access to a global variable tag denotes the language preference (navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language).
- server-side: your server can check a header (Accept-Language) on the I coming request that denotes the locale and serve up different content. This is discouraged because it removes the ability to use a cdn or some high performant environment to serve content.